# Angular 4 MEAN stack: How to get a value depending on another {{value}}

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to angular 4 and dont know how to get my solution.
I get my data from a mongodb and it works fine.

In the field contact.company is the _id from the company. The name of the company is saved in company.name.

Instead of {{contact.company}} (where the id is stored) there should be client.name (which is the name of the company) to show the real name, not the id. How do I get it?

I think I need to call automatically a method, that gets the values from the database?

The full code is here https://github.com/hevilp/angular/blob/master/client/app/contact/contact.component.html

the full code here: https://github.com/hevilp/angular

```
   <tr *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
      <td>{{contact.anrede}}</td>
      <td>{{contact.titel}}</td>
      <td>{{contact.vorname}}</td>
      <td>{{contact.nachname}}</td>
      <td>{{contact.company}}</td>
      <td>
```

and contact.component.ts (code is not working...)

```
getClient() {
          this.clientService.getClient().subscribe(
            data => this.client = data,
            error => console.log(error),
            () => this.isLoading = false
          );
        }
```

Comment: Not clear, can you send me what response you are getting and what you want to print ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understood your problem, tell me I I am geeting it wrong. 
You want to display contact data, but for the field contact.company, you want to display the real name which is gotten from the database, in function of the id : *contact.company* , using the funtion : *getClient(contact)* ?

If so, why do you wait until you display the data to get the real name of the company? Why don't you parse your array of contacts and add a field : *contact_name* from the beginning, I mean in ngOnInit ?

If so , you should add this call to *getContacts()*

```
     getContacts() {
        this.contactService.getContacts().subscribe(
          data => {
            for (let contact of data) {
              contact.contact_name = this.getClient(contact);
            } 
            this.contacts = data
          },
          error => console.log(error),
          () => this.isLoading = false
        );
      }
```

This will make sure that all the data is loaded from the beginning.

I hope it helps. Tell me If I got it wrong or if you are looking for some other solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your code and getting: `ERROR in .../client/app/contact/contact.component.ts (51,39): Cannot find name 'getClient'.`

Comment: `It is working now with = getClient(.this.contact)` but my code in getClient is wrong. `getClient(client) {
          this.clientService.getClient(this.client).subscribe(
            data => this.client = data,
            error => console.log(error),
            () => this.isLoading = false
          );
        }` and `getClient(client): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get(`/api/client/${client._id}`).map(res => res.json());
    }`

Comment: I am sorry, it 's this.getClient. I 'll edit my answer

Comment: I think your function getClient is good. You just have to call it this way, this.getClient(xxx) for each contact you get from the getContacts function

Comment: Ill get CastError: `Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" at path "_id"` the Clientservice.ts `getClient(client): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get('/api/client/${client._id}').map(res => res.json());
    }` I still do not understand how to put the id, which is stored in contact.company to the right http call

Comment: ` getClient(client): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get('/api/client/${client._id}').map(res=>res.json());}`
Do you have an **_id** in your Client Model ?

Comment: Try : 
`let url = '/api/client/' + client._id ;
return this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());`

Comment: Its working right now. the request is going out for every item in contact-array. the response is for example: `{"_id":"59f43f1a3a2fc421c00ad8b1","name":"company2","street":"street 2","zipcode":"45678","city":"city2","__v":0}` but something is wrong with contact_name, its still empty. if I put a console.log around, there is "undefined". I dont know what to do...

Comment: Where did you put a console.log around contact_name ?

Comment: The case is more difficult. I opened another question. I think I need to use [this](http://blog.danieleghidoli.it/2016/10/22/http-rxjs-observables-angular/) my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47004461/how-to-access-property-from-object-returned-by-method/47004477#47004477