# How to access property from object returned by method

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm unable to set the value "contact.company_name" from the method getClient.

```
  getContacts() {
    this.contactService.getContacts().subscribe(
      data => {
        for (let contact of data) {
          contact.company_name = this.getClient(contact);
          console.log(contact);
        }
        this.contacts = data
      },
      error => console.log(error),
      () => this.isLoading = false
    );
  }
```

The response is of  this.getClient(contact) http-request is:

```
{_id: "59f43f1a3a2fc421c00ad8b1", name: "company2", street: "street 2", zipcode: "45678",…}
```

How I can make contact.company_name is like company.name? The id in contact.company is the same id like in company._id. The http-request and response is right.

For example the contact is:

```
{
anrede : "sir"
company : "59f43f1a3a2fc421c00ad8b1"
nachname :"surname1"
titel : "dr."
vorname : "name1"
__v : 0
_id : "59f43f363a2fc421c00ad8b2"   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the company will always exist, simply add `.name` to the end of the line:

```
contact.company_name = this.getClient(contact).name;
```

If it might not exist, you need to check that first:

```
const company = this.getClient(contact);

if (company) {
    contact.company_name = company.name;
}
```

**EDIT**

Now I see how your `getClient` method works, you said that its response is JS object, but it does not return anything and instead subscribing to an observable.

Here is a way how to solve this using `forkJoin` (you will probably need to import that operator to use it):

```
getContacts() {
  return this.contactService.getContacts()
    .flatMap(data => {
      if (data.length > 0) {
        return Observable.forkJoin(
          data.map(contact => {
            return this.contactService.getClient(contact)
              .map(company => {
                contact.company_name = company.name;
                console.log(contact);

                return contact;
              });
          }));
      }

      return Observable.of([]);
    });
}
```

For more examples of how to combine observables, see this article:

http://blog.danieleghidoli.it/2016/10/22/http-rxjs-observables-angular/

Comment: I tried that, but I get: `[1] ERROR in D:/dev/Angular-Full-Stack-master/client/app/contact/contact.component.ts (53,62): Property 'name' does not exist on type 'void'.`

Comment: Sounds like your `getClient` method is defined as `void`, it must return the object you described in the question.

Comment: here it is: `getClient(contact) {
        this.contactService.getClient(contact).subscribe(
          data => this.client = data,
          error => console.log(error),
          () => this.isLoading = false
        );
      }`

Comment: I see, you said that its response is JS object, but it does not return anything and instead subscribing to an observable. Will update my answer.

Comment: I got one last error, after I imported all that: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
import "rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';` The error is: `ERROR in D:/dev/Angular-Full-Stack-master/client/app/contact/contact.component.ts (62,22): Property 'map' does not exist on type 'void'.`

Comment: Return the observable from getClient method instead of subscribing to it.

Comment: Or just use `this.contactService.getClient(contact)` instead of `this.getClient()`, answer is updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157778/discussion-between-hevilp-and-martin-adamek).